# Combining Texures into one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, image

I got a model in Cycles with several materials, each with their own diffuse and normal map.

Is there a way to combine them all into one file so I can use just one material without having to redo the UV Map, especially the normal maps?

Cheers

PS: I am still learning 3d modeling, so I am sorry if this is a trivial question. I couldn't find much through google, but maybe I looked for the wrong thing.

Comment: There is an add-on called "Texture atlas" it can create maps for several objects at once. It temporarily combines all the objects, and you can create single UV map for it combined. Then you can paint this new texture in texture paint mode, using the new map as the target, and your old textures with old UV maps as source. Then you have to change the texture image and the UV map in all the materials you use. I think it will do. But I also think that the idea to have multiple texture files for multiple object is not so bad,

Comment: Thank you, Ill try Texture Atlas out.

Multiple materials certainly have their appeal, but they seem to be quite the hindrance for texture painting in Subtance Painter if they aren't only used for separated meshes (e. g. head and eyes). At least I think so, I suppose I just haven't figured out yet how to handle them properly. :D

Comment: Try to watch on youtube "Creating an Old House in Blender Part 2" (the guy bakes materials to single texture). Anyway, if you want the single texture for separate objects, use texture atlas, otherwise you don't need it. When you join meshes, it joins UV maps too. All you need, to create new UV map to place all the faces on the large image, then transfer data from old images with old UV's to the new one. Paint or bake, main thing is to keep both UV's when transferring.

Comment: I found the shortest possible tutorial on youtube that definitely will do. ;-) Its name is "Remapping Textures In Blender - Remap The UV Layout And Keep The Same Texture" (v=h880hxH-BC8).

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that I figured it out with Texture Atlas. After researching some quirks (having to mark a unconnected texture node for baking is extremly unintuitive, but welcome to Blender I suppose. >.>) I finally managed it to get a pretty good result. It also helped me extremly to understand UV mapping better which lead to me finally beeing able to do some other things I was unable to figure out so far. Thanks for the answers and suggestions!

Comment: You're welcome. Each "blender animal" once goes this "yellow node road". :-)